# Refresh activity after successful API response in android studio

Tags: android, android-api-levels

I have 3 Activities  A B C ::--

I call API for departments list in activity A and each departments has multiple managers with managers details like name , mobile , emails etc.

Activity A (contains department list)
Activity B (contains Manager list for particular department)
Activity C (contains One manager personal details like name , mobile ,email) etc.

Activity A  starts activity B Pressing Back on activity B should lead to A
Activity B starts activity C Pressing Back on activity C should lead to B

In Activity A I get data form API for List View ( Department List). I pass this data in activity B though intent on  list view item click (click of department Cell which contains multiple manager list)  and now  I have list view for managers list and now on click of manager list item I pass data of that particular manager details in Activity C though intent now I call API for updating manager details after successful response of API I want to refresh activity B to refresh manager list how can I do this

Comment: Lets say the updated manager details are coming in the department api and whenever you update any manager detail i am guessing that api has updated data. So in your case you call departments api in Activity A and when you click any item all its details are sent to Activity B. So in your case when you updated manager details in Activity C on success of the api, you can go back to Activity A and then click on the same item and it will take you to Activity B where you can see the updated reponse.

Comment: Whe you finish actvity C, try to use OnActvityResult, see an example her e: https://www.javatpoint.com/android-startactivityforresult-example

Comment: Hascher .. I know that but it can be possible without skiping activitie B ..

Answer (score 0):

3 Options

1. Just always refresh all managers in Activity B in `onResume` or `onStart` - this will ensure you always have the latest information.
2. Use [`startActivityForResult` or the new Results API](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result) to get a result from Activity C. After it updates the manager, pass back the updated information to B and it can use that to update the selected Manager.
3. Use an "offline first" architecture pattern. Activity B would get it's data from a local (Room) database which it always queries in `onResume` or `onStart`, like option 1 but offline. Activity C would update this database once the online fetch completes. On returning to Activity B, the new data is automatically refreshed. Google "android offline first architecture" for more.